# Django queryset returning incorrect data?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-forms, django-queryset, django-nonrel

My setup is a Django-Nonrel running on Google App Engine

I have a Lesson model\form that has LessonStep inline model\forms. The connection is via foreign key in LessonStep pointing to Lesson.
I'm using `save_related` so that once the Lesson form is saved, along with all the LessonStep inline forms, I'll be able to do some data manipulation on the inline models.

This is my code:

```
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(LessonAdmin,self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        logging.debug("inlines: %d" % (len(form.instance.lessonstep_set.all()),)  )
```

The problem is this:

Lets asssume my Lesson form has no LessonStep instances. I add a new one via the Django admin form and save it, which in turn calls this function. What happens next, is that the instance is **indeed being saved in the DB**, but `form.instance.lessonstep_set.all())` returns an *empty* queryset. The logging print comes out as `inlines: 0`

Obviously the data is there, because when the updated admin form comes up it has the new LessonStep instance.

**My question:**

How come the the queryset returns empty, even though the data was just saved via `super`?
Is there a better way to reach the saved inline instances of the model just saved?

More info - 
If I put a breakpoint on the logging line, and evaluate the query, I get a result with the proper queryset returned. So I have a feeling this has something to do with Django caching or maybe the context of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Django (I have no experience of non-rel) caches the related objects queryset. You can avoid this by refetching the instance from the database.

```
instance = Lesson.objects.get(pk=form.instance.id)
len(instance.lessonstep_set.all())
```